# Render one test element of ItemsSource in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a XAML element that I want to style, but as it is inside of a dynamic list (which I set using `Name=""`), I can't see any of my changes while writing the XAML.

Is there a way so that Visual Studio renders one (or a few) test element(s), so that I can see what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `DataContext` of the control then the XAML Designer will pick up any data from it.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</ListBox>


public class MyViewModel
{
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Items = new[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };
    }
}
```